# Python dictionary update based on csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, parent

I have a csv file where:

```
id, word, super_id
100 , cat, 5
5 , bird, Nan
3 , dog, 100
20, fox , 100
```

I created the following dictionary: `d= {100: [5, 3, 20], 3: [100]}`

- where node 100 has parent 5 and children 3, 20
- node 3 has parent 100 and no children

I need to update the dictionary such that it becomes: 
`d= {cat: [bird, dog, fox], dog: [cat]}`
or create a new one.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way using the `csv` module and a couple of dictionary comprehensions:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""id, word, super_id
1 , cat, 2
2 , bird, Nan
3 , dog, 1
4, fox , 1""")

# replace mystr with open('file.csv', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)  # ignore header row, or use headers = next(reader) to extract
    fin_d = {int(ide): word for ide, word, super_id in reader}

d = {1: [2, 3, 4], 3: [1]}

# map keys and values of d using fin_d
res = {fin_d[k]: list(map(fin_d.get, v)) for k, v in d.items()}

print(res)

{'cat': ['bird', 'dog', 'fox '], 'dog': ['cat']}
```

Comment: do you mean to copy the whole csv file and store it in mystr?

Comment: No, I mean replace `with mystr as fin` with `with open('file.csv', 'r') as fin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
import csv


d = {100: [5, 3, 20], 3: [100]}

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    rows = csv.reader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
    next(rows) 
    names = {int(row[0]): row[1] for row in rows}

result = {names[key]: [names[item_id] for item_id in value] for key, value in d.items()}
```

Comment: To get rows you should do it like in `jpp` answer. I modified my answer according to it to make it complete.